# Meet both WHERE criteria - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help refining the WHERE clause on a query for the table below:

```
Key   |   Name   |   Role   |   Location
111   |   Bob    | Manager  |  All Locations
222   |   Jim    | Manager  |  All Locations
333   |   Tim    | Sales    |  Washington
444   |   Roy    | Sales    |  New York
555   |   Lee    | Sales    |  All Locations
666   |   Gus    | Sales    |  All Locations
777   |   Joe    | Admin    |  All Locations
888   |   Jen    | Admin    |  New York
```

I need to exclude all the 'All Locations' records, but keep the 'All Locations' records where the Role is Manager.  To get the desired result:

```
Key   |   Name   |   Role   |   Location
111   |   Bob    | Manager  |  All Locations
222   |   Jim    | Manager  |  All Locations
333   |   Tim    | Sales    |  Washington
444   |   Roy    | Sales    |  New York
888   |   Jen    | Admin    |  New York
```

I feel that the query below would exclude all the All Locations records, including the Manager ones.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (Location <> 'All Locations' AND Role <> 'Manager')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use OR instead of AND

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (Location <> 'All Locations' OR Role = 'Manager')
```

Answer (score 4):

You will want to expand the `WHERE`:

```
select *
from yourtable
where
(
  role = 'Manager'
  and location = 'All Locations'
)
or
(
  location <> 'All Locations'
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db8ab/1)

Returns the result:

```
| KEY | NAME |    ROLE |      LOCATION |
----------------------------------------
| 111 |  Bob | Manager | All Locations |
| 222 |  Jim | Manager | All Locations |
| 333 |  Tim |   Sales |    Washington |
| 444 |  Roy |   Sales |      New York |
| 888 |  Jen |   Admin |      New York |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (Location != 'All Locations' OR (Location = 'All Locations' AND Role = 'Manager')
```

Answer (score 1):

You say "exclude all the 'All Locations' records, but keep the 'All Locations' records where the Role is Manager."  Doesn't that mean ***exclude*** the All location records where role is ***not*** manager? i.e., don't you want records 111 and 222 to be included ??

From De Morgans Law, Not A And Not B   is equivalent to Not (A Or B)

In your case , one predicate is positive and the other negative, so De Morgan would read:

```
  Not (A And not B) <=> (Not A or B), i.e.,
```

That means ***include*** all records that are either Not All Locations or Manager .

If so then what you need is:

```
  ... Where Location != 'All Locations' Or Role = 'Manager'
```